# How do I make Interface Builder recognize IBOutlet/IBAction for new languages?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, pyobjc, ruby-cocoa

it's a theoretical question: suppose I come up with an outstanding new scripting language and want to make a Cocoa bridge for that.

Is it possible to make Interface Builder recognize the new language and parse the source code automatically so that it can list the `IBAction`s and `IBOutlet`s, just as it already does for Objective-C's `.h`, RubyCocoa's `.rb`, and PyObjC's `.py`, and AppleScriptObjC's `.applescript` files? Or is it hard-coded into Interface Builder?

If it's possible, how can I do it and/or is there a document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not documented.

Matt Gallagher did a post a while back on the interprocess communication between Xcode and IB
[Interprocess Communication](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/02/interprocess-communication-snooping.html)

Using those techniques, you may be able to pull something off.

Another thought is to capitalize on what IB already does and generate a .h file with the appropriate IB markers for your language of choice - e.g. write out a .h file with the elements you want exposed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your second suggestion does sound the most future-proof solution! But I need to come up with a new scripting language first :p